# Find which VRF contains a route

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, prefix, command

I am trying to find a Juniper command that shows a list of VRF routing tables that contain a specific prefix / range. Does any one know if this is possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to limit your output to just the names of the routing-tables, then something like:

`show route 192.169.0.0/24 | match dest`

will do the trick